# how to use slug in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

hey everyone i'm having a trouble in using pretty url as i send an ID in each page i use but i want it to be title instead of ID to make it looks fine , i read that `SLUG` can be used but actually i didn't get it very well as it uses elequent model and i use database model , and that's how my link looks like for example :

```
href="{{action('hireController@getIndex','id='.$h->id)}}"
```

and i receive the id in the request like that :

```
$id=$request->get('id');
```

so how can i use it to alter the ID with the title i need ?

Comment: you can use `str_slug` method.It can be helped you https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-slug

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud sorry the link u gave is down now can u help me and tell me about it here ?